# how do I get spring boot to retry when getting mysql dataSource?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

so I have a spring boot application inside docker compose, and it relies on a mysql container, the problem is it tries to open a connection before the mysql container is ready, and it crashes.

I found that I can use

```
spring.datasource.hikari.initializationFailTimeout=0
```

in my application.properties, but only seems to make it wait for a couple of seconds longer before crashing, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly add this to your docker compose in your container config `restart: unless-stopped`

google: 'Unless-stopped' restarts the container only when any user executes a command to stop the container, not when it fails because of an error. 'Always' restarts the container whether the it's caused by an error, or is executed by a user, or if Docker is restarted

Comment: this worked beautifully, i used on failure instead, seemed more appropriate, ive been stuck for hours trying out ways to restart spring or the connection, or setting up the running order in the compose .
you helped me a lot bro thanks